# How to manage a multi-user job scheduler on a single machine

Tags: ubuntu, queue, multi-user

I'm new to the queue / task manager scene and am currently a bit lost in the possibilities.

### What I'm looking for

On a single machine (nothing over an internal or external network), a simple queue that accepts enqueues from multiple users to be run sequentially.

### Specifics

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04

The programs that are being run are computational chemistry packages such as PSI4, NWChem, GAMESS, etc.

These programs require a simple input txt file (made by the user) and the output are txt files as well.

### What I've found so far

In my google searches thus far, I'm come across a lot of options that seem close to what I want.

These seem like overkill

- Torque
- PBS Grid Works
- Slurm

I've also come across these, but still don't know what I'm doing.

- beanstalkd
- cron
- task-spooler
- at/batch
- supervisor

Maybe beanstalkd + cron + self-made python scripts would do the job?

What program(s) are appropriate for what I'm looking for, and some direction on how to set this up would be greatly appreciated.

I apologize if this is too open-ended....

Answer (score 1):

The job schedulers (Torque, Slurm, PBS, etc.) are meant for large clusters and are a bit difficult to install, yet they were designed to do what you want to do. The others were meant for different purposes. `task-spooler` is the one from the second list that looks like what you want but it does not appear to be multi-user.

My suggestion would be to try [condor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTCondor), a job scheduler that is powerful and yet [easy to install/manage](https://www.linux.com/news/setting-condor-cluster).